# TabLayout - Animated round indicator (changes to pill shape)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

How to implement a dot indicated tab layout that changes shape to pill when scrolling view pager.

This is the result I'm having right now, the bubble simply going from one to another.

[image: Result what I got]

This is the result I'm looking for, the bubble should convert to a pill.

[image: Result what I want]

My code for the round shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:innerRadius="0dp" android:shape="ring" android:thickness="4dp" android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

My tab layout

```
   <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
      android:layout_width="45dp"
      android:layout_height="15dp"
      app:tabBackground="@xml/tab_default_dot"
      app:tabGravity="center"
      app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
      app:tabIndicator="@xml/tab_default_dot"
      app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch" />
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use this [lib](https://github.com/tommybuonomo/dotsindicator) 
or look how author implement it

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, but I'm having a small problem with this lib. It is having a default padding in the width, the dots are center-aligned and I would like to remove that padding. `android:padding="0dp"` not working Can you help?

Comment: if author do not provide it functionality you can not change it. The one of possible solution is using this lib as the module library, so you can easy modify it or add your functionality.